# Overriding dependencies in NServiceBus

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nservicebus, spring.net

I'd like to use NServiceBus profiles to override the concrete classes used in the Spring.net dependency injection for use in Integration Testing.

In my `EndpointConfig` class, I have a component being configured:

```
NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<RealCommunicator>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
```

(This bit is OK!)

I created a new profile:

```
public class StubThirdPartyProfile : NServiceBus.IProfile
{
}
```

And a behaviour class to implement it:

```
public class StubThirdPartyBehaviour : IHandleProfile<StubThirdPartyProfile>
{
    public void ProfileActivated()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<StubCommunicator>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
    }
}
```

Both `StubCommunicator` and `RealCommunicator` implement the same interface and I was hoping that the profile would remove the old dependency and use the `StubCommunicator` instead but this is not the case. Is there a way to do this?

When the solution is run, I get the following error:

```
Spring.Objects.Factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating object with name 'Namespace.CommandHandler' :
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through object property 'Communicator': 
There are 2 objects of Type [Namespace.ICommunicator] for autowire by type, 
  when there should have been just 1 to be able to autowire property 'Communicator' of object
```

We're using the Spring.net framework in NServicebus configured as so:

```
Configure.With().SpringFrameworkBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer().Log4Net()
                .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of configuring the real component in the endpoint config class, consider registering it in a class which handles the other NServiceBus profiles - Lite, Integration, Production.

Comment: Thanks Udi, Thats what I ended up doing. Cheers